# Prevent duplicates in MYSQL database from uploaded CSV

Tags: php, mysql, csv, upload

I am using the following script to upload records to my MYSQL database, the problem I can see is if a client record is uploaded and it already exists in the database and is duplicated.

I have seen lots of posts on here about people asking on how to remove duplicates from the csv file itself on upload, e.g if there are two instances of the name bob and the postcode lh456gl in the csv dont upload it, but what I want to know is if its possible to check the database for a record first before adding that record so not to insert a record that already is there.

So something like :

```
if exist namecolumn=$name_being_inserted and postcode=postcode_being_inserted then
  do not add that record.
```

Is this even possible to do ?.

```
<?php
//database connect info here

//check for file upload
if(isset($_FILES['csv_file']) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'])){

    //upload directory
    $upload_dir = "./csv";

    //create file name
    $file_path = $upload_dir . $_FILES['csv_file']['name'];

    //move uploaded file to upload dir
    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['csv_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {

        //error moving upload file
        echo "Error moving file upload";

    }

    //open the csv file for reading
    $handle = fopen($file_path, 'r');

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) !== FALSE) {

        //Access field data in $data array ex.
        $name = $data[0];
        $postcode = $data[1];

        //Use data to insert into db
        $sql = sprintf("INSERT INTO test (name, postcode) VALUES ('%s','%s')",
                    mysql_real_escape_string($name),
                    mysql_real_escape_string($postcode)
                    );
        mysql_query($sql) or (mysql_query("ROLLBACK") and die(mysql_error() . " - $sql"));
    }

    //delete csv file
    unlink($file_path);
}
?>
```

Comment: What you should do is add a unique index across all columns that you use to determine whether the record is a duplicate. That way MySQL won't let you insert duplicates. It can be pretty dumb though, you might need to run a select before you insert if you want to do anything intelligent, like accounting for misplaced whitespace/punctuation in address components

Comment: Hi, the problem is this data is coming from a pre existing desktop based customer record system and the client just exports data from it and imports it in, so there is no primary key being imported, just the fields from their client management software.

Comment: It doesn't have to be the PK, just a unique index. The two are not synonymous, and they are not mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two pure MySQL methods that I can think of that would deal with this issue. `REPLACE INTO` and `INSERT IGNORE`.

`REPLACE INTO` will overwrite the existing row whereas `INSERT IGNORE` will ignore errors triggered by duplicate keys being entered in the database.

This is [described in the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) as:

> If you use the IGNORE keyword, errors that occur while executing the
>   INSERT statement are treated as warnings instead. For example, without
>   IGNORE, a row that duplicates an existing UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY
>   value in the table causes a duplicate-key error and the statement is
>   aborted. With IGNORE, the row still is not inserted, but no error is
>   issued.

For `INSERT IGNORE` to work you will need to setup a `UNIQUE` key/index on one or more of the fields. Looking at your code sample though you do not have anything that could be considered unique in your insert query. What if there are two John Smiths in Wolverhampton? Ideally you would have something like an email address to define as unique.

Comment: Hi, I am just testing it at the moment on a test table, before I release it onto my full db. The fields are going to be ; name, postcode, email, telephone, address, and various other fields related to what fuel type they use. Is it possible to use  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE when uploading and inserting files like this, or will that not work because I am not inserting a primary key with the data ?.

Comment: Ahh I think I see where your coming from now, so if I make lets say the telephone number the primary key in the DB , that is pretty unique for a company so that might work. The problem is, the table I am putting the info into already has a primary key,so I might have to use another table as a temp table to just import the data into first then move it over.

Answer (score 1):

Simply create a UNIQUE-key over name and postcode, then a row cannot be inserted when a row with both values for that fields already exists.

Comment: Hi, the problem is this data is coming from a pre existing desktop based customer record system and the client just exports data from it and imports it in, so there is no primary key being imported, just the fields from their client management software.

Answer (score 0):

I would let the records to be inserted in the database and then, after inserting those records, just execute:

```
ALTER IGNORE TABLE dup_table ADD UNIQUE INDEX(a,b);
```

where a, and b are your columns where you don't want to have duplicates (key columns...you can have them more). You can wrap all that into transaction. So, just start transaction, insert all records (no matter if they are duplicates), execute command I wrote, commit transaction and then you can remove that (a, b) unique index to prepare it for the next import. Easy.